# Laravel many to many relation search

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have three models right now

**User**

```
public function languages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language');
}
```

**Newspaper**

```
public function languages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language');
}
```

**Language**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

public function newspapers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Newspaper');
}
```

I have already have the `language_user`, `language_newspaper` table

And in tinker, I have successfully retrieve both relation by attach() blablabla.

The question is 
How could I search for `Newspaper` that `User` id1 has this `Language` in eloquent? It seems quite complicated for me.

`User id1 -> has language en, zh`

`Newspaper id1 -> has language en, jp`
->OK

`Newspaper id2 -> has language zh`
->NOT OK

I have tried this but not sure if it is correct or not

`$where = [];`

```
foreach ($agent->languages as $language) {
array_push($where, $language->id);}

$newspapers = Newspaper::
join('language_newspaper', function ($join) use ($where) {
    $join->on('newspaper.id', '=', 
        'langauge_newspaper.newspaper_id')
        ->whereIn('langauge_newspaper.newspaper_id', $where);
})
->groupBy('newspaper.id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `whereHas` in this scenario, like this:

```
$newspapers = Newspaper::whereHas('languages', function ($q) use ($agent) {
                 $q->whereIn('id', $agent->languages->lists('id)->all());
              })->get();
```